# addtotoc without a number

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, pdfpages

I am trying to use `addtotoc` key-value in order to make a PDF page appear as a chapter in my Table of Contents.

Ex:

```
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}, scale=1.008, addtotoc={1,chapter,1,Resumen,resumen}]{Resumen_provisional.pdf}
```

However, I do not want the number of the chapter to appear in the table of contents. So I thought of using `\chapter*` inside `addtotoc` instead `chapter`, but it does not allow me to do that, it produces errors within the `.tex` file. Therefore, if anyone knows how to solve this problem, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. Define a "fake chapter" to be used that doesn't have a number. Add the following to your preamble:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \let\l@chapternonum\l@chapter
   \newcounter{chapternonum}
   \renewcommand{\thechapternonum}{}
   \makeatother
   ```

   and use

   ```
   \includepdf[...,addtotoc={1,chapternonum,1,<heading>,<label>}]{<file>}
   ```

   The output should now resemble something like:

   [image]
2. Use `chapter` as the sectional heading in `addtotoc`, but remove the functionality of `\numberline` for that specific ToC-related entry. This will remove the printing of the number associated with that entry:

   [image]

   ```
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\numberline}[1]{}}
   \includepdf[...,addtotoc={1,chapter,1,<heading>,<label>}]{<file>}
   ```

   It is possible to make this one also look like the former, if needed, by updating the `\numberline` macro to set an empty box of pre-specified width. That is, by using

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\numberline}[1]{\protect\makebox[\@tempdima]{}}}
   \makeatother
   \includepdf[...,addtotoc={1,chapter,1,<heading>,<label>}]{<file>}
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much Werner but how could I make it so that it only affects that chapter name and not the ones written after that? Is there any special command? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: @grkz: Add `\let\oldnumberline\numberline` to your preamble, and add `\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\numberline\protect\oldnumberline}` after your `\includepdf` command. This should add a restoration of `\numberline` to its original form - `\oldnumberline`, saved in the preamble - at the correct place inside the ToC.

Comment: Thanks so so much!! This has been the first time I have ever used this kind of helping forums and I didn't think it would be that helpful, but you actually have helped me a lot and I really appreciate it. Thanks so much Werner!!

Comment: I'm attempting to use option 1. here, and while it _does_ look right for the toc, for some reason, it added in the text (e.g. "Resumen") directly on the page I referenced (e.g. embedded pdf page 5). I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Same problem and solution found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385063/159385