# addtotoc without a number and without a header on the inserted page

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, pdfpages

I want to add the bibliography of an external pdf, which I inlcluded by the `pdfpages` package, to my TOC without giving it a number. I found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314780). My problem is that the `<header>` option of `addtotoc` is appearing also on the top of the inserted page!. So, I want to get rid of it.

MWE:(don't forget to change "`pages=34-37`" and "`1512.pdf`")

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \usepackage{pdfpages}

    \makeatletter
    \let\l@chapternonum\l@section %chapter
    \newcounter{chapternonum}{}
    \renewcommand{\thechapternonum}{} %[1]{\chapter{#1}}
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %level 3 for \subsubsection 

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Supersymmetry bla bla}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{1st Section}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \subsection{1st Subsection}
    \lipsum[3-5]
    \subsubsection{1st Subsubsection}
    \lipsum[3-5]
    \section{2nd Section}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \subsection{2nd Subsection}
    \lipsum[3-5]

\includepdf[pages=34-37,addtotoc={34,chapternonum,3,Bibliographie,lab:refcont1}]{1512.pdf} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\l@chapternonum` is to blame for this.

Comment: you can try `\includepdf[pages=34-37,addtotoc={34,section,10,Bibliographie,lab:refcont1}]{1512.pdf}` here 10 can by any  number `>3=secnumdepth`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `addtotoc` option does rely that there is a command  `\l@chapternonum` if the `section` type is named `chapternonum` (as in the linked solution by Werner) as well as it tries to add a 'section' title with a macro named `\@chapternum`, which is not present of course. If this macro is not defined, it adds the header with

```
\expandafter\@sect\AM@temp
         \hskip\z@\par\vskip-\parskip\vskip-\baselineskip\hskip\z@
```

leaving the heading hanging around in the margin.

The easiest way to solve this is

`\newcommand{\@chapternonum}[2][]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}`,

since the definition within `\AM@addtotoc` seems to be a little weird.

Here's the relevant code from `pdfpages.sty`

```
\newcommand{\AM@addtotoc}{}

\def\AM@addtotoc{%
  \begingroup
  \def\@seccntformat##1{}\def\@makechapterhead##1{}%
  \def\@endpart{}\def\partname{}%
  \def\autodot{}% KOMA classes
  \def\ch@pt@c{\the\AM@toc@title}% memoir classes
  \let\AM@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
  \def\addcontentsline##1##2##3{%
    \AM@addcontentsline{##1}{##2}{##3}%
    \def\thepart{}}%
  \AM@addtotoc@hook
  \edef\AM@temp{{\AM@toc@section}{\AM@toc@level}%
           {\z@}{\z@}{\z@}{}[\the\AM@toc@title]{}}%
  \edef\AM@tempi{\noexpand\csname @\AM@toc@section\noexpand\endcsname%
                 [\the\AM@toc@title]{}}%
  \@ifundefined{@\AM@toc@section}
    {\expandafter\@sect\AM@temp%%%%%% This is the culprit!!!!!
     \hskip\z@\par\vskip-\parskip\vskip-\baselineskip\hskip\z@}
    {\AM@tempi}%
  \xdef\@currentlabel{\@currentlabel}%
  \label{\AM@toc@label}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Solution:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\providecommand{\phantomsection}{}

\makeatletter

\let\l@chapternonum\l@section %chapter
\newcommand{\@chapternonum}[2][]{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\edef\@currentlabel{#1}}%
\newcounter{chapternonum}
\renewcommand{\thechapternonum}{} %[1]{\chapter{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %level 3 for \subsubsection 

See \ref{lab:refcont1}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Supersymmetry bla bla}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{1st Section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{1st Subsection}
\lipsum[3-5]
\subsubsection{1st Subsubsection}
\lipsum[3-5]
\section{2nd Section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{2nd Subsection}
\lipsum[3-5]

\includepdf[pages=1-3,addtotoc={1,chapternonum,0,Foo,lab:refcont1}]{7.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The code to generate `7.pdf` can be found in my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367702/31729)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. When I compile your solution, I obtain a number `1.3` before `Foo` as a section which I don't want

Comment: @LlavDem: Yes, I posted an intermediate version accidentally. Try again please

Comment: Thanks again, it works as I wanted. As a side remark, `hyperref` does not go to the right "Foo"'s page, is this relevant to your code?

Comment: @LlavDem: It is since `\addcontentsline` is different when `hyperref` is included -- see the update in `\@chapternonum` with `\phantomsection` and a proper `\@currentlabel

Comment: Now, it's perfect.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!